# Block mail sending to Only Yahoo & Gmail domain in Postfix

Tags: linux, ubuntu, postfix

I want to block mail sending to yahoo or gmail from my mail server but I want to continue receiving mails from yahoo/gmail. I am using ubuntu 10.04 LTS, postifx mail server with mysql virtual mailboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to work with `transport_maps`. So put in `main.cf`

```
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
```

Then in `/etc/postfix/transport` put

```
gmail.com     error:You are not allowed to contact Google
googlemail.com     error:You are not allowed to contact Google
yahoo.com     error:You are not allowed to contact Yahoo
```

Don't forget to `postmap /etc/postfix/transport` afterwards.

Note that this will only deny the mentioned domain names. Not the MX records at all. Yahoo and Google have plenty alternative domain names that you have to take care of. So it would be probably better to firewall their MX servers. Which on the other hand will deny all mails to domains hosted at Google Apps or Google for Business.

Answer (score -1):

Try postfix restriction classes, i believe it's what you need.
Reference: http://www.postfix.org/RESTRICTION_CLASS_README.html#internal

Comment: This will only work for incoming mail.